# volume of tilted ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, volume, multiple-integral

I'm supposed to calculate the volume of
$$(2 x+y+z)^2 + (x+2 y+z)^2 + (x+y+2 z)^2 \leq 1$$
simplifying it gives $$6 (x^2 + y^2  + z^2) + 10 (x y + y z + x z) \leq 1$$

After drawing it using GeoGebra, I saw that it's a tilted ellipsoid inside the unit sphere, but I'm unable to think of how to solve this.
I tried replacing the coordinates and I tried using spherical coordinates but I was unable to go anywhere with them.

The final answer is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ meaning it's $\frac{1}{4}$ of a unit sphere's volume, and still, I wasn't able to conclude anything useful from it. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Let $X=2x+y+z$, $Y=x+2y+z$, $Z=x+y+2z$ then the volume of the given ellipsoid $E$ is
$$V=\iiint_E 1\, dxdydz=\iiint_{X^2+Y^2+Z^2\leq 1} f(X,Y,Z)\, dXdYdZ$$
where $f(X,Y,Z)$ is a [suitable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). Since here the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) is linear, the function $f$ is constant and the integral on the right reduces to this constant multiplied by the volume of the unit ball. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the linear map
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
and notice that your ellipsoid $E$ is the preimage of unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^3$ via $A$ (or image via $A^{-1}$).

Therefore

$$\operatorname{vol}(E) = \operatorname{vol}(A^{-1}(\operatorname{Ball}(\Bbb{R}^3))) = \left|\det A^{-1}\right| \operatorname{vol}(\operatorname{Ball}(\Bbb{R}^3)) = \frac1{\left|\det A\right|} \cdot \frac43\pi = \frac13\pi.$$

Comment: thank you, I think you have an error in the last step, det(A)=4

Comment: @Titan3i Thanks, fixed.